# Text Stored in Indian Languages Retrieved as ???? in Servlet Application

Tags: java, servlets, encoding, utf-8, multilingual

My scenario is like this:
I have a table in SAP HANA XS where some fields will have values in various Indian languages. The servlet which is deployed on SAP BTP Neo environment does a OData $filter to the HANA XS system over HTTP GET request. While reading the stream, the response for such values comes as ??????

I have tried doing the below without any success:

1. Save my Java file in UTF-8 encoded format
2. UTF-8 encoding with the response
3. Pass headers Accept-Encoding and Accept-Charset to UTF-8

The same piece of code when written in a normal Java class and run locally works fine. Not sure what causes this issue when written in a servlet. Have attached the code here, need help from experts here.

````
URL urlObj = new URL(executeURL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
//          connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
//          connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "utf-8");
//          connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "Charset=windows-1255");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userPass.getBytes()));
connection.setDoInput(true);

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer responseStrBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = (in.readLine())) != null) {
        responseStrBuffer.append(inputLine);
}

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
jsonObj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(responseStrBuffer.toString());```
````

Comment: There's nothing there to show how you visualize the result

Comment: Hello g00se, I get a json result like below. The question mark you see here are in an Indian Language Tamil. We are able to store the values in that language in the table. The same issue is happening for all such Indian languages:              {
     "OptionID": "000003",
     "Sequence": "3",
     "Text": "?????????????????????| ???????????????  |??????????????? | ????????????| ????????????????????? |???????????????????????????  |???????????? ?????????????????? ???????????????????????? |  ????????????????????? |???????????????????????????"
    }

Comment: It still doesn't tell me *where* you're seeing that

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am seeing that in the UI application (browser) from where my servlet is called

Comment: What about [this page](https://www.masteranylanguage.com/c/r/o/Tamil/Tests)?

Comment: Didn't understand that link g00se. The scenario is the UI application fetches from the database through a servlet. While the database has the values stored in Tamil, Hindi, Marathi, etc... the servlet which fetches it gets the response as specifies in the question. Since the Java application passes it as '?????' for example, the UI also renders the same.

Comment: The link simply shows Tamil characters. Do you see them properly?

Comment: Yes g00se, I can see

Comment: Any way I can test the same request?

Comment: This is resolved now... Had to set HttpServletResponse type = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'.  response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");